# Show a web page, once connected to an open wifi hotspot

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot, hostapd, authorization

I'm trying to create a wifi hotspot without encryption on my Raspberry Pi 3, by using [Hostapd](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hostapd).

How can I show a window with my own web page every time someone connects to it?

I think the closest example of that I need is, then you connect to a wifi in a hotel - it ask you to authorise. I need the same but with my own web page.

Thank you.

Comment: What you want is called captive portal. Google hit gave me:   https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-a-wireless-hotspot-with-captive-page-in-linux-using-coovachilli/

Comment: @Stephen Rauch, thank you! It become easier to google :)